# Excel VBA ADODB Acces 2003 vs 2013

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I have an excel file that uses an ADODB connection to pull data out of a database. The file has worked fine for months and is used by several employees. Over the weekend, it stopped working on computers that have Access 2003 but still works fine on computers with Access 2010, all computers have Excel 2010. I checked the reference library for each computer and they are all have the same references selected (ActiveX 2.7). It crashes (Unspecified Error) at “cn.Open MyConn”. IT assures me that no updates to Excel or Access were made over the weekend.

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection

stDB = "K:\SHARED\Gross Planner\Gross Planner 2003.mdb"
MyConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & stDB & ";"
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open MyConn
```